# How to set Default value as null or 0 to Select drop down Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a select drop down code is like this in some cases it is hidden , when the select drop down is hidden i want to send null or 0 instead of empty value when i save the form how to do that.

```
         <div class="col-md-4" [hidden]="!cpSettlement">
            <select
            class="form-control"
            name="settlement"
            [(ngModel)]="settlement"
            [required]="cpSettlement && payTermOptions"
          >

            <option [value]="'Net'">Net</option>
            <option [value]="'Monthly'">Monthly</option>
            <option [value]="'Quarterly'">Quarterly</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your save method you can simply do

```
save() {
   this.settlement = this.cpSettlement ? this.settlement : null;
}
```

In this case if `cpSettlement` is `true`, you'll have the value of settlement from dropdown options. Else if `cpSettlement` is `false` means the dropdown is hidden so the value will be `null`.

UPDATES

```
            <div class="col-md-4" [hidden]="!cpSettlement">
                <select
                class="form-control"
                name="settlement"
                [(ngModel)]="settlement"
                [required]="cpSettlement && payTermOptions"
              >

                <option value="Net">Net</option>
                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

If you're assigning a static value for the options, you don't need to use angle braces like you did `[value]`. Instead you should just use as in normal html options values. `value="Monthly"`.

Comment: still the value is going empty please help in html can we do

Comment: Hi @Kirubel can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465922/angular-7-expected-2-arguments-but-got-1-error