# Angular 7 Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 error

Tags: javascript, angular

it says this,

> checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name); An argument for
>   'textAccessHeader' was not provided

```
 private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName,textAccessHeader) {
    if (countryName === 'Japan' && textAccessHeader == 'BANK_ADD') {
      this.payment.bankAccountName = null;
      this.payment.partyAccountNameAlt = this.supplierData.legalName;
      this.selectedCountryValidator = '^([\uFF61-\uFF9F]|[()., _-])*$';
      this.accountBeneficiaryName = 'Japanese half-width Katakana - 日本語の半角ｶﾀｶﾅ';
      this.branchNameLocal = 'Japanese half-width Katakana - 日本語の半角ｶﾀｶﾅ';
      this.bankNameLocal = 'Japanese half-width Katakana - 日本語の半角ｶﾀｶﾅ';
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not providing the second parameter textAccessHeader, add one and it will be fixed

Comment: this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name)  how to add inside this one can you change the code please  this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name)

Comment: this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name) , it has only one parameter here you need to add the second one for example this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name, "BANK_ADD" )

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Either make the second parameter optional

```js
private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName: string, textAccessHeader?: string) {
  ...
}
```

Notice the question mark in the type definition of the parameter

or send in `null` as the second paramter

```js
private checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(countryName: string, textAccessHeader: string) {
  ...
}
```

Calling statement

```js
this.checkNonEnglishCharacterCountries(idArray[0].name, null);
```